# Exposing kubernetes clusteer to "the world" without Load Balancer of cloud provider

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

Thus far I've set up a kubernetes cluster that runs my NodeJS deployment. I am now ready to expose it to "the world" and after reading up on services to do this, I believe all of them require a Load Balancer. Usually these Load Balancers are created by a cloud provider that is hosting kubernetes. I came across several limitations with these, some are priced highly, some have limits on connections etc...

I am now trying to figure out how to avoid these Load Balancers and expose my kubernetes cluster, but in a performant, secure and manageable way. I've looked through documentation and there seem to be mentionings of things like `NodePort` and `Ingress`. As far as I understood `NodePort` only works for a single machine in the cluster? and `Ingress` still  requires traffic to come from somewhere, usually a Load Balancer.

This is my current manifest, where should I go from here in terms of exposing it to the public, ideally with a method that allows SSL certs, rate limiting etc... usual stuff you'd need in production

**development.yaml**

```
---
# ClusterIP
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: development-actions-cip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: development-actions
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4000
---
# Actions NodeJS server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: development-actions
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: development-actions
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: development-actions
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my-image/latest
          name: development-actions
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
              protocol: TCP
```

Comment: We ran into the same challenge. Unfortunately after an exhaustive search, we realized that regardless of whether you expose a vm, or you expose a load balancer you are going to get charged for ingress. Once you accept that, you can reduce your costs by not using the built in ingress router for k8. That user load balancer rules which are expensive. We instead use  a single load balancer rule and then our own ingress running traefik https://docs.traefik.io/

Comment: If you can create an extra micro instance, you can run a Load Balancer in NGINX: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem there are some ways:

1. You can use a service known as MetalLB which is a popularly used for bare metal deployments. It provides a network load balancer.
2. If you do not want to use the load balancer provided by the cloud provider you can create your custom load balancer with help of a reverse proxy (may be Nginx service). This machine can be a dedicated instance that can be only loaded with routing and load balancing capabilities. The ingress controller that you create after this can be allowed to take traffic from this machine. This is user defined edge creation.
3. As mentioned in the solution above you can use `hostNetwork:true` with your nginx-ingress Pods so that these machines can directly be accessed over the machine network.
4. You can use the externalIP directly with the nginx ingress pods where you can directly assign a public IP to the service and connect the service over the internet.

For more information and setup details visit the official documentation for Nginx ingress at:  https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service

I have tried all of these options for deploying my application and my suggestion would be that if you are using some cloud service to deploy your cluster use the cloud service provider's load balancer as it is much more secure, highly available, and reliable. I you are using on premise deployments go for the user defined edge creation, or MetalLB service

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy the nginx ingress controller in a selected and dedicated kubernetes node using `hostNetwork: true`. This would mean nginx will listen on port `80` and `443` on the host VM network. Assign floating public IP to the VM. Add the public IP of the VM as `A record` into your DNS providers configuration to route traffic for your domain to the VM.

Then for all the backends pods just create clusterIP service and ingress resource to expose it to outside world.

To make it HA you could replicate the same setup to more than one kubernetes nodes.